# Recebendo todos valores na Lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Meu código tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
var a = ViewData["a"];
var b = ViewData["b"];
var c = ViewData["c"];
var d = ViewData["d"]:
foreach(var x in ObjetoE).where(x=> x.A == a && x.B == b && x.C == c && x.D == d){
// Faz alguma ação
}
```

No caso, meu `ObjetoE` seria mais ou menos assim:

```
public class ObjetoE
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
}
```

O que acontece é que os valores definidos para as variáveis `a`,`b`,`c` e `d` são atribuídos de forma dinâmica, no caso, pela `ViewData`, **podendo ser nulos**.
No caso o que gostaria de entender é se existe algo que pudesse pegar todos caso uma variável for nula, como um `*` de uma `query`. Pois acaba sendo inviável trabalhar como condicionais validando se a variável é nula e gerando diversos `foreach` a base de cada condição.

Comment: O problema parece ser interessante, mas eu não entendi o que você está querendo. Talvez seja proposital mas este código não faz sentido.

Comment: @bigown Editei, agora talvez faça um pouco mais de sentido. Mas é que basicamente a minha pergunta se resume ao fato de que eu preciso ter X opções na minha lambda, mas algumas podem vir nulas e as mesmas devem ser ignoradas. Não tenho intenção de verificas condição e aplicar diversos foreach validando se as variaveis de entrada são nulas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer vários `if`s e filtrar o `IEnumerable` que no final vai ser iterado em um único `foreach`, não sendo necessário colocar um `foreach` para cada `if`:

```
var items = ObjetoE as IEnumerable<TipoDoElemento>;
if (a != null)
    items = items.Where(x=> x.V1 == a);
if (b != null)
    items = items.Where(x=> x.V2 == b);
if (c != null)
    items = items.Where(x=> x.V3 == c);
if (d != null)
    items = items.Where(x=> x.V4 == d);

foreach(var x in items)
{
    // Faz alguma ação
}
```